# How to close main window from another class?

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qdialog, mainwindow

I have a class which inherits from `QDialog` (dialog_game_over). I show an object of that class in a slot of another class. I want to close `mainwindow` and `QDialog` when user clicked on `ok` button. First I built an object of  `mainwindow` in `dialog_game_over` and close it. But this way it wasn't correct. What do I do for closing program in class other than main class?

```
dilog_game_over::dilog_game_over(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),x_size(400),y_size(400)
{
    ok=new QPushButton(this);
    ok->setText("OK");
    ok->move(200,200);
    connect(ok,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(on_ok_clicked()));
 }
 void dilog_game_over::on_ok_clicked()
 {
   accept();
   this->close();
 }
 class Myenemy1 : public QGraphicsObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public slots:
  void loss();
  private:
  dilog_game_over dlg;
}
void Myenemy1::loss()
{
  ....
  dlg.exec();
}
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),size_of_plane_y(600),size_of_plane_x(2500)
{
  set_scene();
  put_cloud();
  put_point();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All over your application you can exit by :

```
qApp->quit();
```

Or

```
qApp->exit(0);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.if possible visit this question.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596801/how-to-restart-an-application-in-qt]